# What is the SPARQL query to check if a graph exists and return a message?

Tags: sparql, fuseki

I want to check if the graph exists in my Fuseki server and if it does, it should return a message like

> The graph exists

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with an ASK query. For example, to check that a named graph `http://example.org/graph1` exists, you can do this:

```
ASK WHERE { GRAPH <http://example.org/graph1> { ?s ?p ?o } }
```

It will return `true` if it exists, `false` otherwise.

Comment: Will this work if the graph exists but there are no triples in it?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor good point, probably not. But most SPARQL implementations that I'm aware of do not support the notion of an empty graph - it either has triples or doesn't exist. Sesame (on which I tested this) does this, and though I haven't tested, I thought Jena did as well.

Comment: I don't know what Jena does, but I do note that The SPARQL 1.1. Update section [§3.2.1 CREATE](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-update-20130321/#create) says that "For stores that record empty graphs, [CREATE] will create a new empty graph in the store with a name specified by the IRI."  So there's at least a provision for stores recording empty graphs.